# I am trying to make a MovieClip follow another MovieClip until contact. One MovieClip moves by Accelerometer

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

This is part of my code but still the enemies don't follow the ship. Any idea what can I do? the ship moves by accelerometer and the enemies spawn from -y coming down the screen. Some help would be really appreciated

```
        //Move Enemies towards Player//
        var speed = 5;
        if( enemies.x < ship.x )
{
    if( enemies.x + enemies.speedX > ship.x )
    {
        enemies.x = ship.x;
    }
    else
    {
        enemies.x += enemies.speedX;
    }
}
else if( enemies.x > ship.x )
{
    if( enemies.x - enemies.speedX < ship.x )
    {
        enemies.x = ship.x;
    }
    else
    {
        enemies.x -= enemies.speedX;
    }
}

if( enemies.y < ship.y )
{
    if( enemies.y + enemies.speedY > ship.y )
    {
        enemies.y = ship.y;
    }
    else
    {
        enemies.y += enemies.speedY;
    }
}
else if( enemies.y > ship.y )
{
    if( enemies.y - enemies.speedY < ship.y )
    {
        enemies.y = ship.y;
    }
    else
    {
        enemies.y -= enemies.speedY;
    }
}

        //move enemies//
        if (enemies.length != 0) {
            for (var j: int = 0; j < enemies.length; j++) {
                enemies[j].y += 5;
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: First of all, if **enemies** is (most probably) an **Array**, what's the point in addressing **enemies.x** and **enemies.y**? Basically, you mess with non-existent **x** and **y** properties (that has no meaning on the **Array**) then add +5 to all enemies' **y**-coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Organis. Enemies does appear to be an array so to acces their x and y you would need enemies[0].x. To fix this I'd put the x positions in a for loop like you have for the y coordinate.

Alternatively depending on how many enemies you have I would add a class to the enemy. That way an enemy would spawn and know what to do through it's class. I think this would be simpler as it wouldn't require tidying up an array when an enemy gets removed. You could also adapt it so that each enemy has a random value for speed allowing for more dynamic results.

Good luck

**Edit:**

Okay, thats my bad just realised I wasn't very clear. what I ment is this:

```
 //move enemies//
    if (enemies.length != 0) {
        for (var j: int = 0; j < enemies.length; j++) {
            enemies[j].y += 5;
        }
    }
```

Works fine. Every enemy will move 5 once they are referenced. Why don't you copy and paste the rest of your code into this loop but instead of using enemies.x use enemies[j].x.

I do think the class for each individual enemy would be a better solution and I do think you should have a look into it.

Hope that makes more sense and apologises again.

Comment: With all due respect, this is not the answer to the question. I advise you to **answer** a question only if you are positive you can (and you totally should) provide a working fix, or at least a well-commented guidelines that would help OP to understand things, to overcome mistakes and to solve the problem.